# Getting duplicate rows while using DISTINCT in mysql database

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT distinct user_id as "User Id",
       date(date_created) AS "time",
FROM user
WHERE date_created BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1630141526) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1646039126)
  AND status = 'CONFIRMED'
  AND organization_uuid = '// organization id';
```

**This is my sql query I use the distinct for removing distinct user id but my query return duplicates user id.**

I am getting user id = 139555 two times even i use distinct keyword

[image]

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: But your results ARE distinct aren't they, you have two different dates. you need to aggregate, not distinct.

Comment: i just need distinct user id but for using this query in "grafana" is required time field also thats why i include date in query. @Stu
But i always need distinct user id if same user id with two different dates available i only want to keep any one of them

Comment: So for ID 139555, which of the TWO *distinct* dates do you want?

Comment: @Stu Any one of them.

Comment: Then you have an answer below.

Comment: Okay I got it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to use an aggregate function instead of `DISTINCT`, if you want to get  minimum per user_id you can try to use `MIN` otherwise use `MAX` to get maximum per user_id.

```
SELECT user_id as "User Id",
       MAX(date(date_created)) AS "time"
FROM user
WHERE date_created BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1630141526) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1646039126)
  AND status = 'CONFIRMED'
  AND organization_uuid = '// organization id'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: i just need distinct user id but for using this query in "grafana" i required time field also thats why i include date in query. @D-Shih But i always need distinct user id if same user id with two different dates available i only want to keep only one records